# make error from Makefile generated from premake

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, premake

I'm getting the following output from the console when trying to run make.

```
==== Building Project (debug) ====
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, echo Creating obj/Debug, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make[1]: *** [Project.make:90: obj/Debug] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:30: Project] Error 2
```

The makefile is generated using premake and I have no experience with makefiles. the make file looks like this:

```
# Alternative GNU Make workspace makefile autogenerated by Premake

ifndef config
  config=debug
endif

ifndef verbose
  SILENT = @
endif

ifeq ($(config),debug)
  Project_config = debug

else ifeq ($(config),release)
  Project_config = release

else
  $(error "invalid configuration $(config)")
endif

PROJECTS := Project

.PHONY: all clean help $(PROJECTS) 

all: $(PROJECTS)

Project:
ifneq (,$(Project_config))
    @echo "==== Building Project ($(Project_config)) ===="
    @${MAKE} --no-print-directory -C . -f Project.make config=$(Project_config)
endif

clean:
    @${MAKE} --no-print-directory -C . -f Project.make clean

help:
    @echo "Usage: make [config=name] [target]"
    @echo ""
    @echo "CONFIGURATIONS:"
    @echo "  debug"
    @echo "  release"
    @echo ""
    @echo "TARGETS:"
    @echo "   all (default)"
    @echo "   clean"
    @echo "   Project"
    @echo ""
    @echo "For more information, see https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki"
```

and the premake5.lua file is this:

```
workspace "Workspace"  
    configurations { "Debug", "Release" } 

project "Project" 
    kind "ConsoleApp"   
    language "C++"   
    targetdir "bin/%{cfg.buildcfg}" 
    files { "**.h", "**.cpp" } 
    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines { "DEBUG" }  
        symbols "On" 
    filter "configurations:Release"  
        defines { "NDEBUG" }    
        optimize "On"
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: the Project.make file looks like this:

```
# Alternative GNU Make project makefile autogenerated by Premake

ifndef config
  config=debug
endif

ifndef verbose
  SILENT = @
endif

.PHONY: clean prebuild

SHELLTYPE := posix
ifeq (.exe,$(findstring .exe,$(ComSpec)))
    SHELLTYPE := msdos
endif

# Configurations
# #############################################

RESCOMP = windres
INCLUDES +=
FORCE_INCLUDE +=
ALL_CPPFLAGS += $(CPPFLAGS) -MMD -MP $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES)
ALL_RESFLAGS += $(RESFLAGS) $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES)
LIBS +=
LDDEPS +=
LINKCMD = $(CXX) -o "$@" $(OBJECTS) $(RESOURCES) $(ALL_LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
define PREBUILDCMDS
endef
define PRELINKCMDS
endef
define POSTBUILDCMDS
endef

ifeq ($(config),debug)
TARGETDIR = bin/Debug
TARGET = $(TARGETDIR)/Project.exe
OBJDIR = obj/Debug
DEFINES += -DDEBUG
ALL_CFLAGS += $(CFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) -g
ALL_CXXFLAGS += $(CXXFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) -g
ALL_LDFLAGS += $(LDFLAGS)

else ifeq ($(config),release)
TARGETDIR = bin/Release
TARGET = $(TARGETDIR)/Project.exe
OBJDIR = obj/Release
DEFINES += -DNDEBUG
ALL_CFLAGS += $(CFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) -O2
ALL_CXXFLAGS += $(CXXFLAGS) $(ALL_CPPFLAGS) -O2
ALL_LDFLAGS += $(LDFLAGS) -s

endif

# Per File Configurations
# #############################################


# File sets
# #############################################

GENERATED :=
OBJECTS :=

GENERATED += $(OBJDIR)/main.o
OBJECTS += $(OBJDIR)/main.o

# Rules
# #############################################

all: $(TARGET)
    @:

$(TARGET): $(GENERATED) $(OBJECTS) $(LDDEPS) | $(TARGETDIR)
    $(PRELINKCMDS)
    @echo Linking Project
    $(SILENT) $(LINKCMD)
    $(POSTBUILDCMDS)

$(TARGETDIR):
    @echo Creating $(TARGETDIR)
ifeq (posix,$(SHELLTYPE))
    $(SILENT) mkdir -p $(TARGETDIR)
else
    $(SILENT) mkdir $(subst /,\\,$(TARGETDIR))
endif

$(OBJDIR):
    @echo Creating $(OBJDIR)
ifeq (posix,$(SHELLTYPE))
    $(SILENT) mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
else
    $(SILENT) mkdir $(subst /,\\,$(OBJDIR))
endif

clean:
    @echo Cleaning Project
ifeq (posix,$(SHELLTYPE))
    $(SILENT) rm -f  $(TARGET)
    $(SILENT) rm -rf $(GENERATED)
    $(SILENT) rm -rf $(OBJDIR)
else
    $(SILENT) if exist $(subst /,\\,$(TARGET)) del $(subst /,\\,$(TARGET))
    $(SILENT) if exist $(subst /,\\,$(GENERATED)) rmdir /s /q $(subst /,\\,$(GENERATED))
    $(SILENT) if exist $(subst /,\\,$(OBJDIR)) rmdir /s /q $(subst /,\\,$(OBJDIR))
endif

prebuild: | $(OBJDIR)
    $(PREBUILDCMDS)

ifneq (,$(PCH))
$(OBJECTS): $(GCH) | $(PCH_PLACEHOLDER)
$(GCH): $(PCH) | prebuild
    @echo $(notdir $<)
    $(SILENT) $(CXX) -x c++-header $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) -o "$@" -MF "$(@:%.gch=%.d)" -c "$<"
$(PCH_PLACEHOLDER): $(GCH) | $(OBJDIR)
ifeq (posix,$(SHELLTYPE))
    $(SILENT) touch "$@"
else
    $(SILENT) echo $null >> "$@"
endif
else
$(OBJECTS): | prebuild
endif


# File Rules
# #############################################

$(OBJDIR)/main.o: main.cpp
    @echo $(notdir $<)
    $(SILENT) $(CXX) $(ALL_CXXFLAGS) $(FORCE_INCLUDE) -o "$@" -MF "$(@:%.o=%.d)" -c "$<"

-include $(OBJECTS:%.o=%.d)
ifneq (,$(PCH))
  -include $(PCH_PLACEHOLDER).d
endif
```

Comment: This makefile appears to invoke *another* makefile named `Project.make` in the working directory. Do you have that file?

Comment: @Beta Yes. I edited my post to include that.

Comment: Is this `mingw32-make`? Install [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/), install the regular (sane) `make` in it (using `pacman -S make`) and use it instead.

Comment: The generated makefile says `SHELLTYPE := posix` but the error message `CreateProcess(…)` suggests a non-POSIX shell. Try [premake docs](https://premake.github.io/docs/system) on `system`.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The error message appears to be associated with this rule from `Project.make` ...

```
$(OBJDIR):
    @echo Creating $(OBJDIR)
ifeq (posix,$(SHELLTYPE))
    $(SILENT) mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
else
    $(SILENT) mkdir $(subst /,\\,$(OBJDIR))
endif
```

... and I infer from the appearance of `CreateProcess` in the diagnbostic message that you are trying to perform this build on Windows.

The issue is a failure to create a subdirectory `obj/Debug` of the working directory.  Sometimes such diagnostics are misleading as to the specific nature of the problem, but here are some possibilities:

- the Windows branch of the implicated rule appears to be relying on "command extensions" to be enabled in order to create two directories with one `mkdir` command.  They are enabled by default, but they can be disabled either globally or on a per-processes basis.  If they are disabled at least for the `cmd.exe` process in which you are performing your build then the failure you describe is likely.  In that case, you could probably work around that particular issue by manually creating the `obj` directory, but you might face other, similar ones.
- Alternatively, you may simply not be authorized to write in the project folder.

Comment: Hi! I've made sure that command extensions are enabled. I've also tried merging the two directories into one, but it throws me the same error. And I tried running make with an administrator account but it still throws me the same error.

Comment: Looks like it's failing the echo commands for some reason. I created obj/Debug folder myself and it threw me the same error but with "process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, echo Linking Project, ...) failed."